# R Sorting of Multi-Column Data

Tags: r, sorting

I'm having a peculiar problem sorting the data frame that follows (sds45) in the column `stat0`;

```
>sds45

           icntr     iexpt angle overlap Specified.Shot.Width          V6 mcsp             stat0
DD.Sigma2      3   1R50_50    45       0                   50 rectangular  1.5  3.62075986666667
DD.Sigma5      6   1R50_35    45      15                   50 rectangular  1.5  1.07005992333333
DD.Sigma8      9   1R50_40    45      10                   50 rectangular  1.5        1.36916201
DD.Sigma11    12   1R50_30    45      20                   50 rectangular  1.5 0.951408239333333
DD.Sigma14    15  1R100_75    45      25                  100 rectangular  1.5  11.6972803333333
DD.Sigma17    18  1R100_80    45      20                  100 rectangular  1.5  13.4350596666667
DD.Sigma20    21  1R100_90    45      10                  100 rectangular  1.5         16.654366
DD.Sigma31    32 1R100_150    45      50                  100 rectangular  1.5  2.19166406666667
DD.Sigma34    35 1R100_160    45      40                  100 rectangular  1.5         5.4822418
DD.Sigma39    40  1C200_25    45      75                  100    circular  1.5       0.704197414
DD.Sigma42    43  1C200_50    45      50                  100    circular  1.5  1.03405964333333
DD.Sigma45    46  1C200_75    45      25                  100    circular  1.5  7.03481966666667
DD.Sigma48    49  1C200_80    45      20                  100    circular  1.5  9.19375816666667
```

My first approach was this:

```
test<-sds45[order(sds45$stat0),]
```

... which did nothing.

I also tried this:

```
test=orderBy(~stat0, data=sds45)
```

I must have a basic concept problem.  I would appreciate a small bit of education on this.

Comment: is the stat0 column numeric?  funny things happen when you sort character vectors!  your first try with `order` should work great if you're ordering numbers.

Comment: My bet is that some of your columns are factor instead of character / numeric.  In which case they would be sorted by their underlying codes, not their levels.  Use `str(sds45)` to check.

Comment: Your first approach works on my side. Is `stat0` a numeric column? What does `str(sds45$stat0)` give you?

Comment: Thank you all.  stat0 appears a character column.  Is there a quick way to convert/interpret as numeric?

Comment: @bob123: `sds45$stat0 <- as.numeric(sds45$stat0)`.

Comment: Thanks Joshua,  I found I needed to use "as.double".  All works well now.  Many thanks to all! Bob

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon... It turns out that since stat0 is a factor I need to do this;  
> sds45$stat0=format(sds45$stat0, digits=2)

> sds45$stat0=as.numeric(sds45$stat0)
> in order to coerce in into a proper numeric.  I don't have any idea why.  But it works.

Comment: @bob123: See the FAQ on R 7.10: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f

Answer (score 3):

When the data frame was created, there were probably some non-numeric characters in `stat0`, and so that column was converted to be a factor.  When you sort on the factor, you are sorting by the underlying level codes, which would be ascribed in the order that those values appeared, thus the order doesn't change.

<del>The solution is to convert that column to be numeric.</del>

You can convert that factor to be numeric, as you intended it to be, using:

```
factor_to_numeric <- function(f)
{
  as.numeric(levels(f))[as.integer(f)]
}

sds45$stat0 <- factor_to_numeric(sds45$stat0)
```

It is <del>also a good idea</del> **very important** to check your dataset to try and find those non-numeric characters.  If that column contains dirty data, then the rest of your dataset may also need cleaning.

Comment: The solution is to fix the underlying problem, not to plaster over it by forcing the column to be numeric.

Comment: @hadley: Agreed.  I've fixed the language to clarify the point.